# How to target Linux Platform on Delphi?

Tags: linux, delphi, windows-subsystem-for-linux, firemonkey, wsl-2

I want to develop an app for Linux using Delphi, but Linux isn't a target platform option on my side:

[image: Delphi IDE with Projects and target platforms]

What are the steps to start developing and compiling apps for Linux using Delphi?

What do I need?

Comment: Did you read the documentation yet? [Linux Application Development](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Linux_Application_Development)

Comment: 1. Check if your Version Supports Linux as Target 2. See if Plattform is installed: Tools -> Manage Plattform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Here's a full guide for developing apps for Linux using Delphi:

### Setting up WSL2 (Linux Environment):

1. Download `Ubuntu` from the `Microsoft Store`:
   [image: Ubuntu WSL on Microsoft Store]
2. Once Ubuntu is installed, you can click on the `Open` button and set up your account:
   [image: Ubuntu Terminal]
3. Make sure your Ubuntu WSL is fully up to date using the following command:
   [image: Update Ubuntu]

`sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

4. Setup Delphi PAServer using the following command
   [image: Setup Delphi PAServer on Ubuntu WSL]

`curl -L https://embt.co/SetupUbuntu4Delphi22 | bash`

5. You can then launch/run Delphi PAServer with the following command:
   [image: Run Delphi PAServer]

`~/pa22.sh`

### Setting up the Delphi IDE:

1. You need `Delphi 10.4` or newer installed. This also needs to be the `Enterprise Edition` of the IDE.
2. Additionally, you need to make sure you have the Linux Platform installed in your IDE:
   [image: Delphi Platforms Install]
3. You need to install `FMXLinux` from the `GetIt Package Manager`:
   [image: FMXLinux on GetIt Package Manager in Delphi]
4. Go to `Tools > Options > Deployment > Connection Profile Manager` and set up a connection to your PAServer in the Ubuntu WSL:
   [image: Delphi Connection Profile Manager]
   [image: Connetion successful]
5. Go to `Tools > Options > Deployment > SDK Manager` and add a new Linux SDK:
   [image: Delphi SDK Manager]
   [image: Add SDK in Delphi SDK Manager]
6. Now you can then create a new Multi-Device Application (FireMonkey/FMX) and you should see Linux as an option:
   [image: Create a Multi-Device Application - Delphi (FireMonkey - FMX)]
   [image: Delphi IDE with Projects and target platforms with Linux selected]
7. If you don't see Linux, then you simply need to add it by right-clicking and selecting "Add Platform":
   [image: Add Platform]
   [image: Linux Add Platform]

---

And that's it. Now you should be able to compile and build applications for Linux using Delphi.

Comment: If `sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y` doesn't work, then try the solution in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/91595/872212 (This worked for me)